# browser.click() & browser.send_keys() conflict - Selenium 3.0 Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am currently trying to implement a subtitle downloader with the help of the http://www.yifysubtitles.com website.

The first part of my code is to click on the accept cookies button and then send keys to search the movie of interest.

```
url = "http://www.yifysubtitles.com"

profile = SetProfile() # A function returning my favorite profile for Firefox
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

WindowSize(400, 400)
browser.get(url)

accept_cookies = WebDriverWait(browser, 100).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "cc_btn.cc_btn_accept_all")))

accept_cookies_btn = browser.find_element_by_class_name("cc_btn.cc_btn_accept_all")
accept_cookies_btn.click()

search_bar = browser.find_element_by_id("qSearch")
search_bar.send_keys("Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print "Succesfully clicked!"
```

But it only works once - if not randomly. If I turn on my computer and run the code, it does click, make the search and print the last statement. The second time, it doesn't click but still make the search and print the final statement.

After each try, I close the session with the `browser.quit()` method.

Any idea on what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify wait for button and search bar it should solve your problem.

Thanks,D

Comment: Yes my friend, although I also slightly altered the one for the cookie button.